# Calling reloadData in UITableViewController not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

When my app loads up it builds a menu using a `UITableViewController`, this menu is split in two parts.  The first part has 4 items from a 'hard-coded' array, the second part is made dynamically from a list of all text files in the documents folder.

When my app runs it builds the menu and then gets files if they're needed (which the menu needs to be complete).  So the second part of my menu is blank.  If I run the app again the menu is fine as the files now exist.

What I want is, when the file has finished downloading, for the `UITableViewController` to be reloaded and so the menu rebuilt.

The number of files can and will change and will be updated often with a timestamp check carried out just before the file is downloaded.

Where the file is downloaded:

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    MenuViewController *refreshedMenu = [[MenuViewController alloc]init];
    [refreshedMenu reloadTableView];
    // Have also tried:
    // [refreshedMenu performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadTableView)withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO ];
    [file closeFile];
}
```

The `UITableViewController`'s code:

```
-(void)reloadTableView{
    NSLog(@"reloadTableView has been run");
    [self buildMenuArrays];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
 }

-(void)buildMenuArrays{
    self.mainMenu = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"Home", @"Exhibitor", @"Speaker", @"Workshop", nil];

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *docDirectory =  [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];
    NSArray *files = [fileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:docDirectory error:nil];
    self.infoMenu = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (int count = 0; count < files.count; count++) {
        NSString *currentFile = [files objectAtIndex:count];
        if ([currentFile rangeOfString:@".txt"].location == NSNotFound) {
            NSLog(@"File %@ does not contain .txt", currentFile);
        } else {
            NSLog(@"File %@ DOES contain .txt", currentFile);
            [self.infoMenu addObject:[files objectAtIndex:count]];
        }
    }
    NSLog(@"File array = %@", self.infoMenu);
}
```

At the moment, the array is updated and the correct file names are there but `[self.tableView reloadData];` seems to do nothing.

Any ideas?

EDIT

This seems like such a simple process but I see many other people have the same problem.  IS the approach I'm taking fundamentally wrong?  It seems like calling a UITableViewController's reloadData method should be very easy to do, but isn't?

Comment: Your tableView is probably nil, can you set a breakpoint inside the `reloadTableView` method and check the value of self.tableView?

Comment: I have done as you said and self.tableView is not nil, it shows the two array properties having objects in them.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be making a new object of  `MenuViewController` in `connectionDidFinishLoading` method. This will give you a new object allright but where have you added the view of this new TableViewController object into the existing ViewController?

You need to add view of this newly created TableViewController object onto your view hierarchy.

Comment: I did think about that as I was adding it, I am creating an instance of the UITableViewController and perhaps not reloading the 'original' - if so, how do I reload the 'original' or show this 'new' object?

Comment: For that you need to create the reference of the original  MenuViewController object. Make it a property. Allocate memory in viewDidLoad method and add view of MenuViewController in view hierarchy and just call the reloadTableView method in connectionDidFinishLoading method using the reference.

Comment: so in .h: {
    UITableView *tableView;
}
@property (nonatomic, strong) UITableView *tableView;

Comment: and .m: tableView = [[UITableView alloc] init]; ?

Comment: You should also add `self.tableView.dataSource = self` and `self.tableView.delegate = self;`.

Comment: I have those already in place.  How do I then reference the tableView from the connectionDidFinishLoading method in the other class?

Comment: Why do you want to reference the tableView since you call the reloadTableView method?

Comment: I assumed that I would need to point to the existing/original of the UITableViewController that needs to be reloaded as in my original code I seemed to be creating an instance of the class and reloading that? I have probably got the wrong end of the stick somewhere :S

Comment: You seem to be confusing yourself. TableView is a UIComponent. TableViewController is a ViewController which comes with tableview as its root view. Now please tell us what do you mean by original? Have you set up a tableview in IB/Storyboard which you want to reload? Or by original you mean an original TableViewController object which you possibly have created in code and added its view in your view hierarchy?

Comment: In the storyboard I have a UITableViewController called 'Menu View Controller' with a storyboard ID of' MenuVC' that uses a class called 'MenuViewController'.  When the app loads, this UITableViewController is build and is always available as a menu (beneath other views which can be swiped to one side).  When the file is downloaded (first code snippet) I need this UITableViewController to be reloaded.